# running tests on Chrome browser (version 30+) as well as WebView-based apps，by java

Tags: java, selenium, webview, selenium-chromedriver, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Well,guys [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android) just only show the examply in python. i can not code it in java with the same example.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

any advice

Answer (score 0):

The *Java* equivalent code will be:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOptions("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
driver.quit();
```